# C++ v8 persistent scope

Tags: c++, v8, persistent

Can I somehow persistent `v8::Isolate::Scope`, `v8::HandleScope` and `v8::Context::Scope` ?

I know I can create persistent contex - `v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>> pContext(isolate, v8::Context::New(isolate, nullptr, global));` and persistent function, but can I actually persist all scopes listed above ?

So that I can eliminate scopes stack variables like this:

```
v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate); // can I persist isolate_scope ?
v8::HandleScope scope(isolate); // can I persist handlescope ?

v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
    global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "print"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, Print));
    global->Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "require"), v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, Require));

v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>> pContext(isolate, v8::Context::New(isolate, nullptr, global));
v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Local<v8::Context>::New(isolate, pContext);

v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context); // can I persist this ?
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question but here's some generic information:   A `v8::Local` is a reference that goes away when its handlescope goes away.   A `v8::Global` (presumably what you mean persistent) remains until the Global variable has its destructor called or `::Reset(...)`.  It is common to make a `Global<Context>`, as that's the only way to put it in a data structure to keep the context around to do stuff with it later.

Comment: Also, `v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global ` is a terrible name.

Comment: Okay. I will try to clarify a little bit.
Inside my c++ wrapper I have two functions: compile and run. First one create isolate, create scopes, compile, run and save persistent function. And the second on, run function, tries to get the same isolate, create scopes, and just run this already compiled function. https://bitbucket.org/bondarenkoedik/v8final/src v8wrap.cpp file, _run and _compile functions.

So the question is - why nodejs version works faster. Is the problem in GC ? Cuz in my version, if I call _run in a loop I constantly allocate and delete memory and that's may be the case.

Comment: I don't know anything about your node program to tell you what the difference may be.

Comment: I don't use cnode.cpp for tests. I just call run from several thread inside my test simple program.

Comment: Please, if you have a minute, just look at the v8wrap.cpp file, concretely _compile and _run function. Is my understanding of how to use isolates and persistent functions correct ?

Comment: Don't use `    v8::Persistent<v8::Context, v8::CopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Context>> pContext(isolate, v8::Context::New(isolate, nullptr, global));`  use Global instead.   It's not copyable, but that's fine.  You just have to use it like a std::unique_ptr

Comment: recreating isolates is probably not right as it is expensive, but it's not necessarily "wrong"